# Convert string into a Java Date

Tags: java, date, groovy

```
String stringDate = "2013-08-20T12:10:35Z"
```

How can I convert this stringDate into a Date? I have tried the following:

```
def dateString = stringDate.replace("T",":")
Date date = new Date().parse("yyyy-M-d:H:m:s", dateString)
```

The result is not correctly formatted and the parse is deprecated for date.

Comment: Try this:- Date.parse("E MMM dd H:m:s z yyyy", testDate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Java method `static long parse(String s)` is deprecated, but groovy provides a non-deprecated [`parse`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method:

```
def date = Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", stringDate)
```

The format you're using is the ISO 8601 standard format.  Searching on that should provide you with additional information.

Comment: What is the name of the groovy Date class with package?

Comment: It is the same class `java.util.Date`.  Groovy adds additional methods to many Java classes.

Comment: I use that class but GGTS shows that parse is depricated. How can I tell to use the groovy class. Or is this a bug from GGTS?

Comment: isn'T it new Date().parse... instead of Date().parse... ?

Comment: I don't use GGTS, but if it shows that method as deprecated, it's a GGTS bug.  Parse is a static method, so you can call it without creating a new instance.

Comment: @stephan1001 Whenever there is a doubt, run the code in groovy console. That is why it is for. Run `Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", "2013-08-20T12:10:35Z")` in groovyConsole and see the result. Do not rely on the IDE always.

Comment: @stephan1001 If there is milliseconds involved in the date then use the format as `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"`

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up a Java `SimpleDateFormat` object and then call its `parse` method.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") ;
Date result= sdf.parse(input) ;
```

Check [SimpleDateFormat documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for format options.

Comment: I also need hours, minutes and seconds

Answer (score 0):

Make your life easier, use the Grails Joda Time plugin.

http://grails.org/plugin/joda-time

Comment: If this were a Grails question I'd agree with you...  Ah, I see, the question was originally tagged grails but someone (rightly) removed the tag as the question isn't Grails-specific.